# Do I mirror, replicate, copy, copy with sync, etc. my prod db in Azure to create another db to develop new features?

Tags: sql-server, azure, azure-web-app-service, connection-string

I've set up my website (app service) and database (Sql Server) in Azure. Right now it works like this:

> prod website -> prod database

The prod website has connection strings to the prod database and all is good!

What I want to do now is create a dev website (slot), so I can create and test new features.

> dev site (slot) -> dev database

I can create a new app service or just create a slot off my prod site, but I'm not sure if I want my dev database as a mirror, replica or copy of the production database, where if I make changes (test new features) Can I manually or on a schedule update the dev database to whatever the prod is? Ex. every night at midnight re-mirror prod to dev. So any new changes made to dev during the day get wiped out.

**Questions** - What's the best solution for a dev/test db?

1. Mirroring or replication or copying or copy with sync, ...?
2. Is there something else, as I'm new to all the different Azure features?

Comment: Don't test with prod data. A test has to have a known expected result. Prod data is whatever data prod users have entered. You have no control over it, so you can have no expected result. This is a matter of opinion and mine might be controversial in some circles but I have stuck to it for two decades and have never heard an argument that refutes it. The only response has ever been "but I want prod data".

Comment: There's plenty of reasons to want to use prod data and have a dev db set up mirroring prod. I'll give just 1 -> If a user has a bug in prod and you need to replicate it in your dev db, to test, debug, and fix. You might be able to get away without the actual data (that's ok) but the dev db needs to be the same structure as prod

Comment: @allmhuran Question - how do use create and test your dev db?

Comment: The dev db will (practically by definition) always be ahead of prod, unless nobody is doing any dev. If you look at flow like git flow or github flow what you're referring to would be a hotfix, and these are often done against master directly (in database terms, prod directly). If the org objects to that, you can spin up a hotfix environment as needed. The prod schema can be easily extracted using lots of different tools (in ssms, for example, right click database > tasks > generate scripts, or using redgate tooling, etc).

Comment: @allmhuman but, but, but! what if I'm adding a new feature, and in order to implement it and then test it, I need to have data, not necessarily prod data but testable data. If my db is complex with many entities, child entities, etc. and I don't have data in the db when I need to test, then I'd be spending a large amount of time populating data into the dev db for testing purposes! Is that a logical way of looking at it?

Comment: Well under this methodology you would have scripts to generate test data. If you need to add a new feature (= new table, new columns, etc) then you update your data generation scripts to match. Or use tooling that tries to do that automatically (again, redgate for example). But over the years I have concluded that writing the necessary data scripts for testing is so much less effort than the actual development I might as well just do them manually. After all, if it's a new feature (table/column) you can't populate it from prod anyway.

Comment: Now you're proposing a whole ton of unnecessary work with having to generate/write new scripts every time I want to test a new feature? Why would I ever want to spend that much time writing those scripts? Have you not worked on large complex db's with hundreds of tables?

Comment: How do you intend to populate brand new tables and columns from a production system where those tables and colums *don't yet exist*?

Comment: I'm possibly dyslexic, so let me ask a different question. I currently have my site/db built. I'm now testing and feel comfortable moving to a production server (but still not go live). I create my prod site/db and migrate to it. The site gets deployed and the database schema/structure gets built. All is good. Now in a month I go live and users start adding data (profile, images, etc). Now I want to add a new feature to dev, but in order to do so I'll need to have multiple profiles, images, and lots of other table data to test this new feature. Now what, write a script to gen. all data in dev?

Comment: It seems like Azure db replication is what I want, but I've never used it so still reading through the docs. Also I see I can copy a db and/or mirror it. Maybe there's other ways I haven't discovered on top of these mentioned? In previous groups we had a replica/backup made every night to use for development. But maybe this isn't the best way in Aure as we weren't using it and everything was done on site on a MS Server running Sql Server, etc

Comment: You should have written the data generation script when you created the table. *Or you can use tooling that does it*, as I mentioned previously. How did you do any testing before the first release with no data? Furthermore, how does your ability to add a feature depend on what data exists in the database?

Comment: ok, so, I have seed files. These seed files contain json data (user profiles, images, class events, meetup locations, etc, etc) When I first execute "run and debug" there is a Datacontextseed.cs file that looks for data in different db tables, if none is found, then the json files are read, deserialized and the data is added to each and every table. These seed files all assume no data exists Ex. if _dbContext.User.Any() == null  -> read data and seed it into the db.

Comment: From prev... These seed files are now very old and wouldn't work if I tried them again as my db tables have changed significantly since I first seeded data. Well, they might work, if I modified them, but the biggest concern isn't the generic data that can be replicated in a seed file, it's all the transactional data (Stripe, Azure service bus, other micro services I'm calling that return ids and other info). Trying to replicate that data in a seed file seems like it would be nearly impossible and/or very time consuming. So, wouldn't db replication in Azure work for a dev/test environment?

Comment: I think as allmhuran mentioned - having copies of production data in dev environment can be dangerous especially if it contains personal information. I’d advise to keep an up to date seed files for testing environments ( which allows you to run automation tests in a build pipeline).

Comment: ok, maybe I don't need prod data in my dev db. But how do I manage my dev db? Is it a copy, mirror, replica, etc, etc of my prod db? what's the guidance on this and do you have any links you can provide that show a diagram or something?

Comment: Do not move prod data off of prod infrastructure! Keep the two worlds separate. Prod has tighter security and real people's data to keep secure. Dev has valueless data. You can simulate every scenario from prod in dev, and make experimental changes to the db in dev without worry.

Comment: Nobody said anything about moving it, but copying or replicating it to use it for dev/testing is needed! No?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to give you a solution here that covers the concerns raised by myself and others in the comments, but which still approaches what you want to do.

But we have to agree on a premise that provides the logical basis for the entire methodology: The development schema is not identical to the production schema. By definition, it is normally expected to be a newer version of the schema that has yet to be deployed to production. The development schema might have different tables, different columns, different sql module definitions, different constraints, and so on and so forth.

Given that premise, you can't realistically use any technology that tries to keep the data in development "synched" to the data in production in near-real-time. You can't use mirroring or an availability group replica anyway, since those would result in a development database that is either unavailable or read only, preventing you from doing any development.

You could, theoretically, try to set up replication. You would have to author custom replication procedures to do this, that "account for" potential differences in the schema. I leave it as an exercise to the reader to imagine all the difficulties you would face trying to do this.

So, on the basis that there is not (and, really, *cannot be*) any technology that keeps the environments "in synch in near real time" due to potential schema differences, we move to not-near-real-time synch options.

The obvious choice is backup and restore. The production system is being backed up anyway, and it's good practise to make sure those backups are actually working by making sure they can be restored. So, we set up a scheduled job (nightly, weekly, whatever you choose) to restore the production backup to the development environment.

But this is not sufficient, we now have to address a few problems this creates.

First of all, any work that developers had done in development that day is now gone. When they come in the next morning expecting to be able to continue development, they will need to reapply any changes that had not yet made it to production. Trying to do this manually will very quickly become a frustrating nightmare.

So this restore-from-prod strategy really requires that you have some kind of automated deployment for SQL changes. After the production database is automatically restored you would also automate the deployment of any migration scripts that had been executed only on the development environment. This means you need a way of identifying which migrations those are. There are any number of ways to do this, and the decisions on how any particular org should do it are going to involve contingencies and opinions specific to the org. I will not attempt to provide a full SQL deployment automation solution in this answer.

These "migrations" should also include the creation of any data necessary for the new features to function, and any data required for devs to be able to do testing. For example, suppose my prod database has table `T(i int primary key, c char)`. A developer has altered this table for the next version, so it is now `T(i int primary key, c char, d date)`. The developer is obviously going to want to run code that depends on the `d` column. So we need data in that column. This should be part of a test preparation script.

In addition, the data in production is "whatever". You have no idea what rows might have been updated, deleted, or inserted. Therefore if your development team is running integration tests that check for a specific value, or result set, when running their code, those tests are now very likely to fail.

You must therefore also insert specific, known test data, defined *by the implementation team*, for use in the tests so that you can check a result against a known expected result. This should be done for every table. It doesn't have to be a lot of data. A row per reference table, one or two rows per transactional table. These should be created following the usual code paths wherever possible to ensure that any downstream changes are applied.

For example, suppose you are testing an ERP. You want invoice data to test with. But the ERP also manages the general ledger, and changes to invoices should result in changes to the general ledger. If you simply run an insert against the invoice table, you will probably not get the expected changes in the general ledger.

What if those processes have changed in the next version of the system? You need to insert this data *prior to* applying the schema migration, and then and then populate any new/changed dev-only data after the schema migration. What if those processes require calling across application level code spread around a dozen microservices? Then you're going to have a hard time setting this up.

OK, let's say you now have automated the restore of the production database to development, and you have an automatic migration deployment pipeline that brings dev back to what it was before it was replaced by the production restore. Are we done? Not by a long shot.

The next problem is that the database being restored from production will bring across the production users. Suppose I have some application service account that connects to production using either a domain account or a SQL Server auth account created for that application. That account is now able to connect to the dev environment. If you simply leave things as they are and use that account to connect to the dev environment, you run the very serious risk of accidentally connecting to the prod environment from the dev application. The likelihood of this may be low, but the possible consequence of doing so could be Very Bad. It is therefore a better idea to use separate accounts for different environments in your SDLC.

That means we also need to run an environment specific post-restore script that will drop or disable the production users, and add the dev users in their place. The easiest way to manage this is to use a database role for the application. You grant all required permissions to the role. Then, when you finish your restore-from-prod-to-dev, you drop the production user out of the role, and put the dev user in the role.

You're also probably going to want to grant developers their permissions in this script. Devs typically don't have elevated rights on prod environments, but do on dev environments.

Technical detail: If you are using Sql Server authentication for any logins, you will will need to remap the users in the database to those logins using `sp_change_users_login` (deprecated) or `alter user`.

We're still not done. Production databases contain production data. That might mean sensitive data. It could be personal information (which should be encrypted at rest anyway) that development staff shouldn't be able to see. It could mean financial information that development staff shouldn't be able to see.

You can use Dynamic Data Masking (a SQL Server feature) to handle this. Alternatively you can just run a DML script that goes through and updates data in the database, obfuscating any sensitive information. You might replace all email addresses with "noone@myfakeaddress.com". You might incorporate the value of a surrogate identity column into the replacement data if you need these emails to not all be the same for some kind of testing purpose.

Note that running a script like this can result in changes to the statistics histogram, which will change the performance characteristics of queries. Your development environment won't be a good indication of likely production performance if you do this. But to be fair, it probably wasn't anyway. Development environments are rarely a good indicator of production performance for a whole host of reasons already.

If you feel like all of the data-obfuscation tasks here are too onerous, or if your production database is too enormous for your dev resources, there is another option entirely.

Instead of restoring the production database to dev, you drop the dev database and execute the DDL of the production schema to create a new, *empty*, environment that matches the prod schema. You can use lots of different tools to accomplish this (redgate, for example).

But this schema is, of course, empty. So now you run your data population scripts. You must already have some of these. For example, if a developer adds a new table which contains "system defined" (not user defined) information, that must already have been part of some migration script at some point. So you run all of those.

Then to populate the business data you can either execute scripts that you manually authored, or you can use a tool that tries to automatically populate a schema with "random" data. Again, redgate has tooling for this, but there are several options available. This also "solves" your testing issue if you set the rules for how that data is generated, such that you end up with some "known" rows which can feed the expected results of tests.

If you take this alternative, you still need to do the user management.

Comment: Thanks for the post. So, as of now, I created a copy of my db (prod) and then I synced it with a new db (dev). I've set the syncing to take place every 24 hours. But I'm thinking I might just disable auto syncing and do it manually. It seems like this is a good starting point for creating my dev environment? According to some of your comments above, I really only need schema info and can just run scripts for table data. Do you know if there is a way to sync just schema info in Azure, or am I stuck copying everything?

Comment: There are various tools you can use to extract raw schema from an existing system, but there's nothing "built in" to a SQL Server instance by microsoft to take a schema from one database and construct a new database using that script. I'm personally a fan of the various redgate tools (SQL Source control, SQL Compare, etc), SMO is probably another option.

Comment: What's SMO....?

Comment: [SQL Management Objects](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/server-management-objects-smo/sql-server-management-objects-smo-programming-guide?view=sql-server-ver16), a library that provides non-tsql-based programmatic access to most of the operations you can perform in SQL Server

Answer (score 0):

There are few topics to consider:

1. Your release lifecycle, which can be optimised still. Industry practices recommend NOT to replicate Production data to Dev boxes, not even to Test / Integration. Example here could be: your Dev box should work with a schema replica and anonymised data, same for Test / Integration. Only use a sub-set of actual data on Pre-production where your end-users run UAT. In Azure that could translate in (simplest) using 2 resource groups with adequate RBAC,(RG 1 with own App service + database for Test / integration and RG2 using Slots for Pre-Production / Production . In both cases I would suggest using Azure DevOps / GitHub pipelines to publish changes. Content how to do it is everywhere, but I would suggest the start with labs https://www.azuredevopslabs.com or https://dotnetthoughts.net/continuous-database-deployment-with-github-actions or https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/app-service-sql-asp-github-actions if you prefer GitHub.
2. Optimise your deployment of code and even database replication of changes via DevOps starting with storing your source (including databases scripts) in a repository and deploy from there. Example as many(GitHub free, Azure DevOps allows for 5 free Basic licenses with your organisational account, or setup your private one).